# Key violation in CancelUpdates

Tags: delphi, key, constraints

I have a problem with Dataset in master/detail mode.

I'm using **Delphi XE with update 1, DBExpress and Firebird 2.5.2**
I have a master/detail relationship between tow tables (CDS),  defined 
with Master source / masterfield properties.

My problem is that when I drop all the records in the detail dataset and after edit master ClientDataset, when I call the CancelUpdates method in Detail ClientDataSet I recieve the **"key violation"** exception.

This problem only happened with the detail dataset is Empty.

Anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

**Edited:**
People, the problem with "Key Violation" I solved in my framework. 
Not identify for sure what causes the problem, so I isolated the exception temporarily.

In this same structure, there is another problem, which in this case seems a Bug's DBExpress.

In the link below, I created an example to simulate the problem.

http://www.4shared.com/zip/gmT7GVPf/MestreDetalheBug.html

How to simulate problem:

**1) Select a master record;

2) In the grid details, delete all the records, but not save. Only delete by DbNavegador.

3) Go on the grid master and change any value of master record. You will see that the records detail grid reappear in detail.

This problem only occurs when the DataSet Detail is empty.**

I have a framework that maintains all changes to a record cached on the bench and only effective when the user clicks the Save button. The solution I found a while, is in the detail records when they are deleted, already effective in the database.

Any help?

Comment: Some questions: The master/detail is done before the provider or after it (nested client datasets)? by _drop_ you mean **delete** all the detail records of all the master records? did you change the value of the key master fields while editing the master records? By cancelling the updates of the detail, you want to preserve the edits in the master record, but get back the deleted records?

Comment: Jachguate, go to your questions.

Comment: @jachguate, go to your questions. 
1) I open master dataset and after, detail dataset.
2) In my situation, I deleting all detail records only and when execute CancelUpdates is only return detail records deleted.
3) I'm not change the master values, the key values is not visible to user.
4) Exactly, after CancelUpdates, my intention is returning only detail dataset records. 

The problem happened only DetailDataSet and only if it is empty.
Thanks

Comment: My first question is not answered. Better if you edit your question and add a diagram or picture showing the relation of your components, including not only the client datasets, but also the provider or providers and the underlying datasets.

I also still don't have clear if you delete all records for all master records, or only all the records of the active master record.

Comment: @jachguate, sorry for the delay, was providing an example for you to see better. I edited the main text explaining better. Thank you in kindness to help.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem in Delphi 2009.
I just close and reopen the DataSet Detail instead of using CancelUpdates to clear the changes. But I hope there are some better solutions.

Thanks.